# Maui Blazor: Destroying event fires on Windows but not on Android

Tags: android, maui, maui-blazor

I want to save some data in a Maui Blazor app. To do so i wrote the following code in 
App.xaml.sc:

```
protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)
{
    var window = base.CreateWindow(activationState);

    window.Destroying += (s, e) =>
    {
        ShoppingApp.Model.DataManager.saveData();
    };

    return window;
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Tried in Windows and Android.
Windows works, Android don't.
I tried that with a breakpoint on the line
              `ShoppingApp.Model.DataManager.saveData();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On mobile devices, regardless of language used, there is no guarantee of window or app destroy event. The usual approach is to save any time app goes into background ("deactivated").

There is no guarantee app code will ever run again, once app is no longer focused. Mobile OSes reserve the right to kill off an app not in foreground, without warning.

See [app lifecycle events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/app-lifecycle?view=net-maui-7.0), for more info.

(Not referring to `services`, foreground or background, which have different rules.)

Comment: Ok I understand. So now i am react on the "Deactivated" event. That is working in Windows and Android. This way i am saving maybe a little to often, when it's not needed, but i (hope) that this works for shure. Thanks
Sorry, that i cannot rate this answer as useful because I am new here and don't have already the rights?! That's quite strange...